# How can I loop through arrays with *ngIf?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an object like this:

```
"data": [
    {
      "key1": "value1";
      "satisfaction": {
        "yes": 0,
      }
    },
   {
      "key2": "value2";
      "satisfaction": {
        "yes": 4,
      }
    }
]
```

I need to make a *ngIf statement that will display value from keys (key1 and key2) only if "`satisfaction.yes`" exits (is bigger than 0). This is dynamically generated and I never know that I might get.

How can I iterate through `satisfaction[]` arrays and if it is bigger than 0 (exists) display `key1`, `key2` values? What is the best way?

Thanks.

EDIT: after this is done, I need to pass the parameters which should download/export the keys..

Comment: This is a fairly basic / fundamental functionality question. You should start by reading through the tutorial or documentation on the Angular site, it is very well written. If you do want more help then please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please also read [How do I ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Make sure that your questions are specific and not overly broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `this.data.filter(v => v.satisfaction.yes);` inside the constructor.

**Note**: The object properties names `key` must be identical, otherwise you won't be able to execute `*ngFor` loop.

**[Working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/0FVTyiQGoShRpSvEgeIL)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use `forEach` loop on your array and first check if `satisfaction.yes` is > 0 and then display value of other key.

```js
var obj = {
  "data": [{
    "key1": "value1",
    "satisfaction": {
      "yes": 0,
    }
  }, {
    "key2": "value2",
    "satisfaction": {
      "yes": 4,
    }
  }]
}

obj.data.forEach(function(o) {
  if (o.satisfaction.yes > 0) {
    Object.keys(o).forEach(function(e) {
      if (e != 'satisfaction') console.log(o[e])
    })
  }
})
```